postgresql extension function does not exist inside trigger
I have installed pgsodium into the database using CREATE EXTENSION pgsodium.
This is the output from \dx
citext   | 1.6     | public  
pgsodium | 3.1.9   | pgsodium 
plpgsql  | 1.0     | pg_catalog

In PLSQL I can successfully do ..
SELECT pgsodium.crypto_pwhash_str('password');
However when I try to do the same in a trigger function I get the error
ERROR:  function pgsodium.crypto_pwhash_str(text) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT pgsodium.crypto_pwhash_str(NEW.password)

This is the function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_user() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $update_user$
BEGIN
    SELECT pgsodium.crypto_pwhash_str(NEW.password) INTO NEW.password;
    RETURN NEW;
END
$update_user$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

How do I execute the function inside the trigger?

It seems it's related to passing the parameter NEW.password
If I do pgsodium.crypto_pwhash_str('test') in the trigger function, it works.
password is a text column.

Hmm, crypto_pwhash_str is expecting a data type bytea and inside the trigger it's getting a text. The following works pgsodium.crypto_pwhash_str(CONVERT_TO(NEW.password, 'UTF8'))

That function takes type "bytea".
When you do SELECT pgsodium.crypto_pwhash_str('password'), the literal is initially marked as "unknown" type, and "unknown" is compatible with "bytea".  That it, it will silently and implicitly interpret the literal as a bytea.
But the password column is already a known type, "text".  It will not silently cast a text to a bytea.  You would need to add a cast to make that happen.  Something like pgsodium.crypto_pwhash_str(NEW.password::bytea)
